# Memory-Efficient ways to Coerce Large Rasterstack to dataframe?

Tags: r, time-series, raster

I have a large `rasterstack`with `dimensions  : 510, 1068, 544680, 19358  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)`. The goal is to coerce it to a dataframe, keeping all `NAs` as well. Thus, `RasterTopints` is not suitable here. I tried the following but go an error:

```
rasterOptions(format="CDF",overwrite=TRUE,maxmemory = 1e+09, chunksize=1e+08,progress="text",tmpdir="/data/xxxx")
rasterTmpFile("clean_this_after_")

#dat is a rasterstack from 1961-2013 at daaily time step

dat_df=extract(dat,1:ncell(dat))
```

I get the error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 39.3 Gb
```

Is there something wrong with my code or a better way to accomplish the same task?

Thanks.

Comment: This might help [Memory-limits](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html) and this [memory.size](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/memory.size.html)

Comment: Yeah not just that but you would be looking at heat death of the universe long computation time. `Raster` can be gut-renchingly slow when it comes to these big data operations. But I would counter your question with another question; Are you sure you want a dataframe? Even a dataframe this size is going to be ridonculous. Why not a list of matrices?

Comment: @SeldomSeenSlim I get what you mean. The issue is that I have some calculations to make but I don't know how to perform them on raster objects. dataframes are easy to handle. For example, I want to apply `spi` function from package `spei` to time series of each grid point of `rasterstack`. This is tricky to perform but can be easily applied on a dataframe.

Comment: So it looks like the spi() function can handle a `vector()`, a `matrix()`, or a `data.frame()`. There may be life in this one yet Sarge... So `extract()` is really slow at grabbing values. Do you know how this function is structured internally? Does it grab just a vector of the pixels across a stack, or does it look at the neighborhood around a given pixel as well?

Comment: @SeldomSeenSlim `spi` simply works on a time series for each pixel. Just like for each column of a dataframe. Thus, each column in a dataframe is treated independently.

Comment: I will look into the `calc` function which works pixelwise accross multiple layers.